# How to deal with File Path thruogh slots in User Interface?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I want to build a simple interface to my offline Map Project (C++), how can I replace the Path passed to My Function `loadFile("G:/QT/Projects/database/city.osm.pbf");` with Open File so The Function Load File takes the path from the map file I'm choosing ?

[image: My GUI Interface]

Comment: If you have several questions then create several posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::on_action_Open_File_triggered()
{
    QString FileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open File"),"C://","OSM File (*.pbf)" );
    //cout << "File Name \t"<< FileName.toStdString() <<endl;
    string FilePath2 = FileName.toStdString();
    loadFile(FilePath2);
}
```